# Unsupervised text classification with R/Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, r, text-mining

I am relativity new to machine/deep learning and NLP. As a part of my Phd thesis I have scraped vast number of job vacancies (most of them are in Polish, and about 10% are in English ones) and then extracted required skills/competencies. As an output I got a vector of strings contains single skills/competences. I performed initial preparation (removed extra spaces, special symbols, stop words etc.) and built then a frequency distribution table to figure out the most demanded skills. The most commonly required skills were as follow:

```
prawo jazdy kat b ## driver license
umiejętność pracy w zespole ## team work
wykształcenie wyższe ## higher education
czynne prawo jazdy kat b ## driver license
znajomość pakietu ms office ## MS Office
prawa jazdy kat b ## driver license
prawo jazdy kategorii b ## driver license
fluent english
doświadczenie na podobnym stanowisku ## work experience
dobra znajomość języka angielskiego  ## English
excellent english skills
doświadczenie ## work experience
```

As you may see some of these competencies are quite similar. The problem is that job offers were provided by a different employers. European classification of skills/competences qualifications and occupations define about 3500 different competencies for instance.

**My aim is to create trivial classifier using logistic regression, SVM or random forest that would be able to classify skills in real time using pre trained model.** The problem is that I can not label vector of unique skills because of vast number of skills within its synonyms. I spent a while trying to figure out a solution.

So, the idea was to perform cluster analysis and to put similar skills into separate groups (clusters) and then label this clusters. In this case I would have much less group to label. Moreover, I would have a lot of synonyms within each group, which would increase precision of classification (I guess). Using labelled data set I would be able to trained model, and then to classify future job vacancies (skills). However, as I said I am new to machine learning, so I am not sure whether my solution would be good enough.

**So, I am looking for advice/tutorials/links that would help me to solve my problem rather than for complete solutions. I can use both R and Python. Would be appreciated for any help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches.

1. You could use [term-frequency/inverse-document-frequency (tf-idf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) to cluster the vectors. Personally, I would start by first clustering the full text of the original job vacancies and then use this to assign clusters to the vectors. I have the feeling that it will outperform clustering directly the vectors.
   There are implementations both in R and in Python. I would use Python for clustering in a language other than English. You can use [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) from sklearn.

   I've a post on medium with an [example of clustering wikipedia articles in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-documents-with-python-97314ad6a78d) if you are interested.
2. You can start by a list of key/basic skills and then try to match your vectors to the items of this list. For defining a distance between words/phrases you can:

   a. use Jaccard index (ex. see [this](https://sistemanalize.wordpress.com/2017/12/10/big-data-set-similarity-q-grams-overlap-measure-jaccard-index-jaccard-distance/))

   b. use [SpaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity) in Python to find descriptions that are similar. I believe there is a language model for Polish. I haven't tried it but I would use something that is described in ["The Beginner’s Guide to Similarity Matching Using spaCy"](https://medium.com/better-programming/the-beginners-guide-to-similarity-matching-using-spacy-782fc2922f7c). Since you are trying to find the similarity between phrases (not single words) you might also  want to consider [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113939/spacy-strange-similarity-between-two-sentences).